# Why my template to run 2 scripts at the same time fails in node?

Tags: node.js

I have a pretty straightforward piece of `package.json` as such :

```
"dev": "parcel index.html",
"server": "nodemon ./server/server.js",
"start": "npm run dev && npm run server",
```

I am not able to run them at the same time. Only the first one is triggered.
Same thing happens with `npm-run-all` with the command : `npm-run-all server dev`

I have also tried `"npm run dev & npm run server"` with no luck.

`Server.js` is running error free on its own.

How can I get my code running 2 scripts at the same time?

Comment: && is sequential, not forked, you could use `;` in its place, but imo for start you should look into using pm2 to run both for production and for dev use the [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package, purely so both stop, start and restart at same time

Comment: also your want somthing like `parcel watch index.html --no-hmr`, which builds to dist on change, then the ./server/server.js actually serves the dist files, else your have CORS issues, and dev is not the same as production, assuming you want everything on a single port

Answer (score 0):

`&&` waits for the successful exit of a process before executing the next command, or failing due to an error.

A long running process will need to put in the background to run both from the same script. This can be done on *nix with a single `&` after a command as you tried:

```
npm run dev & npm run server
```

This leads to the problem of the first process not being under direct control any more. A <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will kill `server` in the foreground but not `dev`. So next time you run `npm start` there is usually a port conflict.

Now you're entering the realms of process management which gets complicated quickly, you can write scripts to deal with this but it will be a badly implemented version of something that already exists. Easier to use something like [`forever`](https://github.com/foreversd/forever) which takes care of the management for you.

```
npm install forever --save-dev
```

Then

```
forever start -c "parcel index.html"; forever start ./server/server.js
```

Both will be launched the background, and you can use the `forever` commands `list` `logs` `stop` `stopall` to inspect or control them.

Forever also supports [multi app configs](https://github.com/foreversd/forever#multi-app-configuration-files) so you can launch one config rather than every process